# Mulesoft Connector for Azure Service bus returns sessionId as null

Tags: azure, mule, azureservicebus, mulesoft, mule-connector

We have one sessionEnabled queue in azure service bus, and we are setting sessionId for that queue as "orders" before we send it to the queue. In the explorer tab we can see the session value "orders" for all the messages that are in the queue.

But when we try to use Message Listener connector of Azure Service Bus and provide the same "orders" sessionId in its advance tab - the queue still return us an empty sessionId and as a result we cant run our flow and it stops with this error

```
It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver.
```

Are we missing any settings that needs to be checked for session queues to be allowed to send its sessionId so that our mulesoft connecttor can pick it up and start the process ints intended FIFO manner?

Comment: I'm not working with MuleSoft but from the error, you need to configure your message listener connector to use sessions.

Comment: We are giving the same sessionId in our connector.